# How to render numbers in jsp in Persian language?

Tags: java, jsp, localization, persian

I've counter bean and I want to render numbers in jsp in Persian language (۱,۲,۳,۴,۵,۶,۷,۸ ...)

I've wrote function than convert decimal numbers to Persian digits:

```
decimalToPersian("123456"); // return: ۱۲۳۴۵۶
```

So I want to use this function every where in my jsp pages where numbers want to be rendered. like in counter bean:

```
<jsp:getProperty name="counter" property="count"/>
```

Should I write filter for numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using simple [JSP expression tags](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-expression-tag).

1. First import the file where you've defined your `decimalToPersian()`
   method.

   ```
   <%@page import="com.path.to.DecimalToPersianConverter"%>
   ```
2. Then use it wherever you want your persian numbers:

   ```
   <%= decimalToPersian("123456");%>
   ```

Comment: hmm, in this way I need to replace all of number expressions in my jsp views. Any better way? writing somehow Servlet filter?

Comment: If you're doing it on server side, then this way or that way, you'd have to call your method so by and large it's all same. However, If you are looking for a more optimal option then I'd recommend you to do this conversion on client's machine using any client side framework like angularjs, javascript ...